# robots.txt: Does Wildcard mean no characters too?

Tags: robots.txt

I have the following example robots.txt and questions about the wildcard:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /*/admin/*
```

Does this rule now apply on both pages:

**http://www.example.org/admin**
and **http://www.example.org/es/admin**

So can the Wildcard stand for no characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original robots.txt specification, `*` in `Disallow` values has no special meaning, it’s just a character like any other. So, bots following the original spec would crawl `http://www.example.org/admin` as well as `http://www.example.org/es/admin`.

Some bots support "extensions" of the original robots.txt spec, and a popular extension is interpreting `*` in `Disallow` values to be a wildcard. However, these extensions aren’t standardized somewhere, each bot could interpret it differently.

The most popular definition is arguably the one [from Google Search](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt?hl=en#url-matching-based-on-path-values) (Google says that Bing, Yahoo, and Ask use the same definition):

> `*` designates 0 or more instances of any valid character

#### Your example

When interpreting the `*` according to the above definition, both of your URLs would still allowed to be crawled, though.

Your `/*/admin/*` requires three slashes in the path, but `http://www.example.org/admin` has only one, and `http://www.example.org/es/admin` has only two.

(Also note that the empty line between the `User-agent` and the `Disallow` lines is not allowed.)

You might want to use this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /*/admin
```

This would block at least the same, but possibly more than you want to block (depends on your URLs):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*admin
```

Keep in mind that bots who follow the original robots.txt spec would ignore it, as they interpret `*` literally. If you want to cover both kinds of bots, you would have to add multiple records: a record with `User-agent: *` for the bots that follow the original spec, and a record listing all user agents (in `User-agent`) that support the wildcard.